# sending non blocking websocket messages from a single threaded java server

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, websocket, thread-synchronization

I run a gaming website, on a tomcat 7 platform, where a single java server thread handles all the incoming messages, and sends outgoing messages to the clients. The clients are websocket connections.

even though I increased the TCP sockets in the server, I still encounter cases where a websocket message send takes seconds to complete, which holds the entire main server.

I am trying to design a multi threaded solution so that the main server thread will pass the message to a different thread for sending. 
Of course for each connection, the messages must be sent in order.
How can you implement such mechanism ?

Comment: Do you have any code samples to provide?

Comment: there is nothing much to provide. the main server thread calls writeTextMessage(String) to send text message to the connected client. I want to pass this string to another thread/s to handle 

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/websocket/WsOutbound.html#writeTextData(char)

Comment: Short answer: Disconnect clients that aren't keeping up with the server. Whether they're malicious or broken, it's not helping anyone to send them the data way too late.